# Clean up if any left overs from last build

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-14.04, rocket.chat

I have been trying to deploy rocketchat from jenkins. intially I did my own installations for dependencies but now I found the cleanup code given in the tutorial. as fallowing . this code seems inconsistant. I am copying as it is to avoid any confusion. can anyone help incase of corrections as this is failing  with syntax errors.

```
#Clean up if any left overs from last build 
SCREEN_RUNNING=’/usr/bin/pgrep SCREEN’
SCREEN_RUNNING fi NODE_RUNNING=’/usr/bin/pgrep node’ ifNODE_RUNNING fi 
if [ -f   master.zip ]; then rm -f master.zip fi 
INSTDIR=./Rocket.Chat-master
if [   -dINSTDIR fi MONDIR=/home/ubuntu/db
if [ -d $MONDIR ]; then rm -Rf  /home/ubuntu/db fi pwd 
#Install packages we need for the build sudo apt-get  install unzip 
curl         https://install.meteor.com/ | sh 
sudo npm install -g n sudo n 0.10.40
```

Comment: First clean it up so it's legible, then include the actual errors.

Comment: Hi Thank you, I edited now. the error is : Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi"). Though I tried to fix it with my knowledge...not able to fix fully. so putting up here as it was from demo. so someone who is knowledgiable can help. I did not get closing 'if' immediately after condition using 'fi' without statements.

Comment: Yeah the code is a complete mess. This might be a good opportunity to learn some very basic shell programming syntax.